# Is it possible to manually dispatch thunk state in createAsyncthunk

Tags: redux, react-redux, redux-toolkit

Hey fellow programmers,

Been having fun learning react-redux lately, but I do have one question that bothers me.

My understanding is that, by using `createAsyncThunk` it will automatically generates action type constants. (pending, fulfilled, and rejected)

What I wanted to know is that is there any way to manually dispatch action type during `createAsyncthunk` , so that we can have more flexibility in our code.

```js
import { createAsyncThunk, createSlice } from '@reduxjs/toolkit'
import { userAPI } from './userAPI'

// First, create the thunk
const fetchUserById = createAsyncThunk(
  'users/fetchByIdStatus',
  async (userId, thunkAPI) => {
    const response = await userAPI.fetchById(userId).then(
       ...
       dispatch(fulfilled)   // is this possible ?
    ).catch(
       dispatch(rejected)    // is this possible ?
    )

    return response.data
  }
)

// Then, handle actions in your reducers:
const usersSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'users',
  ...,
  extraReducers: {
    // Add reducers for additional action types here, and handle loading state as needed
    [fetchUserById.fulfilled]: (state, action) => {
      // Add user to the state array
      state.entities.push(action.payload)
    }
  }
})

// Later, dispatch the thunk as needed in the app
dispatch(fetchUserById(123))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The point of `createAsyncThunk` is that it generates those action types, _and dispatches them for you automatically.  You definitely do *not* need to `dispatch(fulfilled())` yourself, because that's what `createAsyncThunk` does for you - you just need to return a promise that either resolves or reject, and it dispatches the `fulfilled/rejected` action types based on that.

You *do* get access to `thunkAPI.dispatch`, so you can dispatch other actions if necessary, but you don't need to worry about the `fulfilled/rejected` actions yourself.